# Is it possible to specify which folder I what want to install using bower bower.json?

Tags: github, bower

When I include twitter bootstrap using bower I want to install the files from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist. I do not want all the files I get from the master branch. Is this possible using bower.json?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer currently is NO.(Jan/2014) You get what is in the git repository you are pulling from.

This is not all bad. I you use Bower with [Yoeman](http://yeoman.io/) you can set up a build process that generates the desired result.